# Laravel hasManyThrough wrong withCount and good ->count()

Tags: php, laravel

I have hasManyThrough relation.

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Order::class, Customer::class, 'email', 'customer_id', 'email', 'email');
}
```

Now after something like that...

```
{{ $user->orders->count() }}
```

[image]

I get 14 orders for defined user. It's good. But...

After similar code...

```
User::withCount('orders')...
```

Count is different for the same user.

I see error in debugbar sql info.

[image]

Should be users.email = customers.email...

Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in Laravel 5.5.22: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/22071